# Using functions outside module exports

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to do my best to explain what I'm trying to do, please let me know if something wasn't understandable.

I have a file called `www` where I'm setting up my socket like that

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
require('../store.js')(io);
```

I'm sending the io data to another file to use it properly. To capture the `io` I'm using.

```
module.exports = function (io){

}
```

What I'm trying to do is how could I use the `io` outside from the module.exports in the `store.js` file? I've tried to create a variable and then use it, but that doesn't seem to work. 
Example how I've tried it.

```
var ioData;

ioData.on('connection', function(socket) {
  //Doesn't work
});

module.exports = function(io){
  ioData = io;
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? I have an `express` implementation with an `socket.io` stored inside a single class. I can post it here if you want to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this

**store.js**

```
const store = {
  io: {},
  setIo(io) {
    store.io = io;
  },
  setHandlers() {
    store.io.on('connection', function(socket) {
      // do something with connected socket
    });
  }
};

module.exports = store;
```

**www**

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
var store = require('../store');
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

store.setIo(io);
store.setHandlers(io);
```

Comment: If he adds an eventhandler and ioGlobal is updated, the added eventhandler will be lost, so this isn't a working answer.

Comment: yeah that's correct for the first version, my bad for not looking closely. please check updated answer :)

Comment: One more tip: you could add setHandlers to setIo for ease.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a add the connection event handler into the module export function, since when you change ioData, it doesn't re-add the handler.

```
var ioData;

module.exports = function(io){
  ioData = io;
  ioData.on('connection', function(socket) {
    //Doesn't work
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yeah I could do it like that but I have a one package which seems to be going off multiple times if I do it this way.

Comment: @LewisLarf You want the connection event handler to only happen once if I understand properly?